# How do I use jQuery to click and option and have it populate a field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to have jQuery handle the click of an option and put that value in a field.
The code works except for the part I have in the   tag.
I can't figure out why the part within the bold tag isn't doing anything when clicked, while the text after it does.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="result" style="display: block;">
 <div class="show" align="left">
  <b>This text doesn't work when clicked</b> 
  This text works when clicked
 <span class="name" align="left">113096G</span>
</div>
```

And Here's the jQuery:

```
// When clicking an option, the value populates the #projectsearchid field  
jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    $('#projectsearchid').val($name);
});
```

Possibly there's a simpler way to accomplish this?

Comment: In your html the div has and `id` of `result` but in your jQuery you write `#results`

Comment: Almost all of your code is deprecated . . .

Comment: Thanks: that was just a typo as I was simplifying the code for posting here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var $name = $clicked.parent().find('.name').html();
```

> find(): Description: Get the descendants of each element in the current set of
>   matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.

Thus the method will look inside `<b></b>` for an element with the class name of `name`.. which of course it won't find anything, because in this case the element with the class name of `name` is a `sibling` and not a `child`. You'll notice that it will find something if you add `.parent()`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/b0yfsaow/)

```
$('#result').on('click',function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.parent().find('.name').html();
    //$('#projectsearchid').val($name);
    alert($name);
});
```

Comment: That makes sense now: Thanks for the demo!

Answer (score 1):

firstly, jquery.live is deprecated you should use jquery.on.  the reason your code doesn't work is because when you click on the b element, the e.target is associated with  and not div#result.  when you call:

```
$clicked.find('.name').html();
```

it can't find the span.name because the  element has no children with that class.  the same happens when you click on  as well.  instead do

```
$clicked.parent('#result').find('.name').html();
```

that should get you what you need.